# How can we be friendlier to new users?

Tags: discussion, new-users

What are some nice ways that we can welcome new users to our site?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think we can solve this by implementing Clippy.

[image: Clippy!]

Comment: Undeniably clever ... but this was *irony* wasn't it?

Comment: That welbogging little paperclip has terrible grammar. I want to strangle it until it is indistinguishable from a staple.

Answer (score 4):

The usual SO welcome: answer their questions, critique their answers.

Comment: +1. You forgot; Edit the heck out of their plzsendtehcodez questions. :-D

Comment: Ah, yes - that too especially.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the 'welcome aboard' approach, and it didn't seem to have any repercussions...

We should definitely be friendly to new users *who do the right thing*.

Comment: Typically, new users who do the right thing aren't the problem and aren't the once who are encountering unfriendly responses.

Comment: Did someone say there was a problem??

Answer (score 0):

New user or not, we should treat everybody with respect in our comments and answers.

For new users, give pointers and encouragements before any down-voting. Give reason if we do so. Up-vote when they are doing something right (though may not be great).

Answer (score -4):

Show them a picture of Jon Skeet's pony.